# Пустые utm-метки при получении данных лида Битрикс24 через вебхуки, почему?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Всем привет!

В Битрикс24 настроен входящий вебхук с правами доступа `CRM`, а также исходящий вебхук с типом события `ONCRMLEADADD`.

При обращении какого-либо посетителя сайта через онлайн-чат Битрикса, в самом лиде в `UTM-метки` метки отображаются корректно, например:

```
UTM Source: yandex
UTM Medium: organic
UTM Campaign: (organic)
UTM Content: -
UTM Term: -
```

Но при получении данных лида по вебхуку напротив этих меток стоят значения `null`. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На случай, если кто-то столкнется с подобным. Как оказалось, при получении данных лида из Битрикса, utm-метки имеют значение null, но через какое-то время (я проверял через час) если повторно сделать запрос на получение того же лида, то напротив соответствующих полей utm-меток значения уже будут присутствовать.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема в передаче utm меток. Тех поддержка Б24 сразу ответила что стандартная синхронизация не передает такие данные. https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/sproduction.integration/ подключил данный плагин и все заработала. Но удовольствие не дешевое есть и дешевле. В плагине есть инструкция как настроить сквозную аналитику. По данной инструкции составил тех задание и на кворк нашел исполнителя. Все удовольствие встала пару чашек кофе.